# How can I get only lower case words in one list and upper case words in one list , from a list using python

Tags: python, list, validation, web-scraping, data-cleaning

**The code I have used:**

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import csv

list=['ArvindBholaGujarat...creativedirectorSubhashGhai...director']

items=[]
for i in list:
  item=i.split('...')
  items.append(item)
items

cap=[]
small=[]
for i in items:
   caps=re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*',str(i))
   low=re.findall('[a-z][^a-z]*',str(i))
   cap.append(caps)
   print(caps)
lower_words=[]
for i in cap:
   if str(i)==str(i).islower():
      lower_words.append(i)
```

I have tried using the split() in python and using the islower() and isupper() in python but the required data is not coming.

**The output I expect from the code is:
List:
ArvindBholaGujarati    creativedirector
SubhashGhai            director
**

So basically, the pattern identified here is words with captial letters are put in one list whereas the other list contains all the lower lettered words.

This is what I would like to achieve.
I have written all this code in python and would like to get the help needed if any community member can help.

Comment: `'[a-z][^a-z]*` machtes `"bSOMET!"§$%21346HING"` ... doubt that is what you want. `'[A-Z][^A-Z]*'` matches `"Bsome1234!"§$thing"` as well. Also - you split by ... add resulting list to other lists to iterate over that list to search with regex over the string representation of it .... simplify your approach.

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you for the response, but it seems not to work for my expected result.

Comment: Please post a proper example list, with words containing lower & upper, and words containing only lower chars. Also clarify: you need to split such list on 2 separate lists, one with words containing only lower chars, and the other one with words containing upper & lower chars?

Comment: So my sample data set is similar to this, hence posted the same. So to clarify the doubt, yes I need one column with the words having the capital letter as the first character of the word, and the other column having only words that are completely in small letters. I have the CSV which has messy data in a similar format. Hence trying to clean it up.

Comment: So you want to ignore the words containing caps in the middle of the word? As I said: clarify.

Comment: I want all the words in the string/list. Also, if the words begin with capital letter I want to put them in one list, and if the words are starting with small letters, I want to put them in one another list. then write both the list in one csv file.

Comment: .. So you want 3 lists then?

Comment: list=['ArvindBholaGujarat...creativedirectorSubhashGhai...director']
I already have this list. One list shall have ArvindBholaGujarat,SubhashGhai and other list will have creativedirector,director

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
import re
import pandas as pd

names = 'ArvindBholaGujarat...creativedirectorSubhashGhai...director'

items = names.split('...')
print(items)

cap = []
small = []
for i in items:
    caps = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', str(i))
    if caps:
        cap.extend(caps)

    low = re.findall('^[a-z]+', str(i))
    if low:
        small.extend(low)
    
print(f'Caps are {cap}, and lowers are {small}')
```

Output:

```
['ArvindBholaGujarat', 'creativedirectorSubhashGhai', 'director']
Caps are ['Arvind', 'Bhola', 'Gujarat', 'Subhash', 'Ghai'], and lowers are ['creativedirector', 'director']
```

In caps list, there are names starting with capital letters and in lowers words without any capital letters.

Comment: @BariraUshshaque It is not what you asked for in your question. But I'm glad you got a working solution.

Comment: Exactly not what I wanted but I got an approach. So thanks for it. I have worked on  my solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.findall` with alternate patterns, first a fully lowercase word and then a word starting with uppercase letter (joined with a pipe operator).  You can then use the first letter of the output word to determine which list to add it to depending on whether it is a capitalized word or all lowercase.

```
import re

data      = ['ArvindBholaGujarat...creativedirectorSubhashGhai...director']
cap,small = lists = [[],[]]
for item in data:
    for word in re.findall(r'[a-z]+|[A-Z]\w*',item):
        lists[word[:1].islower()].append(word)
```

output:

```
print(small)
['creativedirector', 'director']
print(cap)    
['ArvindBholaGujarat', 'SubhashGhai']
```